# Call a block in another template

Tags: magento, module, block, magento-1.7

I just create a module name referral. Now I want to place the referral block to another module template file name success.phtml. Can it be done?

referral.xml(in referral module)

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">

            <checkout_onepage_success>
<reference name="checkout.success">
                    <block type="referral/referral" name="referralCallLink"><action method="referralCallLink"></action></block>
                </reference>
            </checkout_onepage_success>
            <!--block type="referral/referral" name="referralAddSession"><action method="referralAddSession"></action></block-->

    </layout>
```

success.phtml

```
<?php if($hasBoughtMCash): ?>
<div> Your 
<?php echo implode(', ',$hasBoughtMCash); ?>
 purchase is successful.
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<h2>Share in Facebook and Earn for Free MCash!</h2>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

Referral.php(block)

```
public function referralCallLink() //success page
    {
    ...

    $collection7 = Mage::getModel('referral/referrallink')->getCollection();
    $collection7->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('eq' => $cust_id));
    $collection7->addFieldToFilter('grouped', array('eq' => $grouped));

        foreach($collection7 as $data3)
        {
         $product = $data3->getData('product');
         $link = $data3->getData('link');
         $imageurl = $data3->getData('url');            
        //facebook
         $title=urlencode('Shop, Save and Get Rewarded at MRuncit.com');
         $url=urlencode($link);
         $summary=urlencode('I just bought  '.$product.' from MRuncit.com and earned some MReward Points!');
         $image=urlencode($imageurl);

        ?>
        <p>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" target="_blank">
        <img src="<?php echo $imageurl;?>" width="30">
        I just bought  <?php echo $product; ?> from MRuncit.com and earned some MReward Points!
        </a>
        </p>
        <?php

        }
    }
```

Results
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the block as child of the success block in your layout XML:

```
<layout_handle_of_the_success_page>
    <reference name="name_of_the_success_block_in_layout">
        <block type="your/referral_block" />
    </reference>
</layout_handle_of_the_success_page>
```

Then you can insert the following line in success.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('referral'); ?>
```

There are some names in the example XML that you have to replace with your own:

- `layout_handle_of_the_success_page` - you will find it in the layout XML of the corresponding module. It should be in the form `module_controller_action` **--> checkout_onepage_success**
- `name_of_the_success_block_in_layout` - also from the layout XML, look for the block with the success.phtml template and its `name` attribute **--> checkout.success**
- `your/referral_block` - that's the class alias of the block that you want to insert in the form `module/class` **--> referral/referral**

Comment: Hi, it is like the Checkout.xml and success.phtml I modify above? It show Fatal Error:Call to undefined function getChildHtml()

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `$this->getChildHtml()` - I updated the code.

Comment: Also, I added layout handle and referenced block name from the posted checkout.xml. But please DO NOT edit checkout.xml, add the XML code to your own layout file!

Comment: I successfully call out the block,but it still not in the position.=( It should under the "Share in Facebook and Earn for Free MCash!". Did I do something wrong? I updated the code

Comment: Then your `//PLACE THE REFERRAL BLOCK HERE.` is the correct position. Anything else is probably a problem with CSS

Comment: Ok ok i try play around with the CSS, billion thx for the help. =)

Comment: Hi, just notice that is not CSS problem, is just that $this->getChildHtml() is not function, even i delete this code it would not cause any effect

Comment: 1.) The [original template](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml) already contains a call to `getChildHtml()` (without parameters => all children). 2.) did you forget `echo`?